# My service shutsdown when acticty exits and unbinds to it, would like it to keep running

Tags: android

I'm trying to creat a bacckground service that will have a thread that adds one to a counter every minute.
I want other apps to be able to call a methed call getBot that will retunt the value.

Right now I have a test app that has a activty that bindss to the app so it can talk to it to get the counter.  When it exits it unbounds to it.
It has a button called botGert that gets the current counter value from the service.

When it unbounds to it, the service shuts down.  How can I get it so it does not shut down????

service class
public class MessengerService extends Service {

```
/** Command to the service to display a message */
static final int MSG_SAY_HELLO = 1;
static final int MSG_BOT_GET = 2;
static final int MSG_BOT_SET = 3;
static final int MSG_BOT_STOP = 4;
static final int MSG_BOT_PAUSE = 5;
static final int MSG_GET_ORDERS = 6;
static final int MSG_GET_POINT = 7;

static final int MSG_BOT_GET_RES = 2;

static final int PRICE_STATIC =1;
static final int PRICE_PERCENTAGE =2;
static final int PRICE_ALL = 3;

static final int VOL_STATIC = 1;
static final int  VOL_PERCENTAGE = 2;
static final int  VOL_ALL = 3;

int counter;

boolean isStop=false; // put bot in pause ste on next 1 min update
boolean isUYpdateNextMinute=false;
/**
 This is called by a client to exicute code in this service
 */
class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_BOT_GET:
                Message resp = Message.obtain(null, MSG_BOT_GET_RES);
                Bundle bResp = new Bundle();
                bResp.putString("respData", Integer.toString(counter ));
                resp.setData(bResp);
                try {
                    msg.replyTo.send(resp);
                } catch (Exception e)
                {

                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
             default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}

final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

/**
 * When binding to the service, we return an interface to our messenger
 * for sending messages to the service.
 */
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "binding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// emplanent callbacks

MessengerService parent;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    parent=this;

}
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ThreadDemo T1 = new ThreadDemo( "Thread-1");
    T1.start();
```

// sgart 1 minute update thread

```
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// thread code that runbs counter

class ThreadDemo extends Thread {

```
private String threadName;

ThreadDemo( String name) {
    threadName = name;
    System.out.println("Creating " +  threadName );
}

public void run() {
    try {
        do {
            counter++;
            Thread.sleep(1000 *60 );
            counter++;
        } while (true);
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(parent, "thread stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} // end inner thread class
```

} // end class

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
activity class

public class ActivityBoundMessenger extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bound_messenger);
}

/** Messenger for communicating with the service. */
Messenger mService = null;

/** Flag indicating whether we have called bind on the service. */
boolean mBound;

/**
 * Class for interacting with the main interface of the service.
 */

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // This is called when the connection with the service has been
        // established, giving us the object we can use to
        // interact with the service.  We are communicating with the
        // service using a Messenger, so here we get a client-side
        // representation of that from the raw IBinder object.
        mService = new Messenger(service);
        mBound = true;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        // This is called when the connection with the service has been
        // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed.
        mService = null;
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public void sayHello(View v) {
    if (!mBound) return;
    // Create and send a message to the service, using a supported 'what' value
    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MessengerService.MSG_SAY_HELLO, 0, 0);
    try {
        mService.send(msg);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void butSet(View v) {
    if (!mBound) return;
    // Create and send a message to the service, using a supported 'what' value
    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MessengerService.MSG_BOT_SET, 0, 0);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("data", "json object");
    msg.setData(b);

    try {
        mService.send(msg);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void butGet(View v) {
    if (!mBound) return;
    // Create and send a message to the service, using a supported 'what' value

    Message msg = Message
            .obtain(null, MessengerService.MSG_BOT_GET);

    msg.replyTo = new Messenger(new ResponseHandler());
    // We pass the value

    try {
        mService.send(msg);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// these metheds get called whenb this acty starts and endsa
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Bind to the service
////////////////////////////////////////////
    Intent ser = new Intent(this, MessengerService.class);
    startService(ser);
    bindService(ser, mConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
///////////////////////////////////////////

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Unbind from the service
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
}



// This class handles the Service response
int ted=0;
String nextUpdate=null;
class ResponseHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        int respCode = msg.what;

        switch (respCode) {
            case MessengerService.MSG_BOT_GET_RES:
                String nextUpdate= msg.getData().getString("respData");
                ted++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Basics):

> When the last client unbinds from the service, the system destroys the service, unless the service was also started by startService().

So, all you have to do is call this in your `onCreate()` method in the Service:

```java
startService(new Intent(this, MessengerService.class))
```

Of course make sure to call `stopSelf()` when you are done with the service.